# unable to render all Micro apps with SSR in a single port - angular

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-universal, micro-frontend

I created a angular micro front-end app using angular elements/web components, which is worked perfectly but facing SEO issue. And further I decided to go with SSR but unable to implement in micro front-end instead it create individual app with individual port.

Tried to implement Angular universal SSR , But it was very easy to in Single app application but while I have multiple apps rendering on the single page using Angular custom element concept , I was unable to succeed as each app will served in different port which is very difficult to put all together in to single page rendering using nginx.